# unlike facebook page api

Tags: facebook, api

searched around on a way to unlike facebook fan page but no success

the only way i figure out is : 
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?method=delete&url=http://www.facebook.com/FNAPAGE&access_token=

error :

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) App does not have permission to make this call",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}

so is there a way to unlike facebook fan page ? whatever if its through php or java api .

Answer (score 1):

In the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) documentation, under the [Likes connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#likes) there's nothing about changing/deleting or even adding likes, it just has a way of reading the user likes.

So as it looks, currently you have no way of automating this, and you'll have to manually go to each page you want to remove the like.

Comment: There's no way to do this, and it's intended like that by Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook API v2, released April 30th, 2014, includes an end point for deleting a like.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes#delete